# Module specific layout plugin works as .ini resources but not when registered in the bootstrap file

Tags: zend-framework

I'm currently working on loading a different layout file per module.

I have added the following to my config.ini file

```
; Module Support
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"

; Module-based Layout Support
resources.layout.pluginClass= "Layout_Plugin_ModuleLayout"
```

And the following Controller Plugin:

```
class Layout_Plugin_ModuleLayout extends Zend_Layout_Controller_Plugin_Layout {    

    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        $this->getLayout()->setLayoutPath(
            Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()
                ->getModuleDirectory($request->getModuleName()) . '/layouts'
        );
        $this->getLayout()->setLayout('layout');
    }   
}
```

Everything works fine, but I would prefer to register this plugin in the bootstrap file along with the other plugins. When I move this plugin to the Bootstrap file and register it like this:

```
 protected function _initLayouts() {
   $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
   $front->registerPlugin(new Layout_Plugin_ModuleLayout());
 }
```

I get the following error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function setLayoutPath() on a non-object in C:\workarea\web_projects\gam\trunk\website\library\Layout\Plugin\ModuleLayout.php on line 31

Obviously, I'm doing something wrong or have misunderstood how this plugin works.

EDIT: Eventually used a modified version of the solution at http://dustint.com/post/28/per-module-zend_layout. However I'm open to suggestions about this. This solution uses a normal controller plug, whereas I suspect that I should be making us of the layout plugin type. However, it worked.

Comment: I always use a standard plugin which, I think, is a pretty standard appraoch. The plugin `Zend_Layout_Controller_Plugin_Layout` is primarily a framework-level class that hooks into the dispatch cycle and allows controller-specific view content to be injected into a layout script. It's not really intended as an extension point for our app-specific plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually used a modified version of the solution at http://dustint.com/post/28/per-module-zend_layout.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the layout resource initializes a couple of things, if you look at the source of Zend_Layout_Controller_Plugin_Layout, you need to pass the layout to use, so you may need to do this on your bootstrap:

```
protected function _initLayouts()
{
     $this->bootstrap('layout');
     $this->bootstrap('frontController');
     $layout = $this->getResource('layout');

     $front = $this->getResource('frontController');
     $front->registerPlugin(new Layout_Plugin_ModuleLayout($layout));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, I tried that but it creates a Circular resource dependency error.

Comment: Yeah, I see that now, I think the aproach you edited is the correct one, I personally use a controller plugin to switch the layout based on the module, so I think that's the correct way to do it.